# how to use tinyMCE as a automatic spell checker in django?

Tags: django, tinymce, spell-checking, django-tinymce

Is there any option for automatic spell checker( while typing) in tinymce?.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a javascript code that sets the spellcheck value to "true" after the TinyMCE editor loads.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:spellchecker

These look less useful:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:gecko_spellcheck
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:iespell

Comment: here the problem is that it will check after clicking on spellchecker button. But i want it to work like ms-word spell checker. Is there any command i am missing?. and i am using IE8..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `django-tinymce`, it should be a matter of turning the plugin on in `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG`. Then you can place the button where you want it. For example:

```
'theme_advanced_buttons2': "allmystuff,...,spellchecker",
'plugins': "abunchofplugins,...,spellchecker",
```

This assumes a folder named "[spellchecker](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3aspellchecker)" under /tinymce/plugins which is available in your static files somewhere.